# JFrame MouseExited

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener

I am starting in Java and my school gave me some homework, that when the mouse leaves the window it closes, the problem is that it closes when I try to hit the buttons.

```
private void formMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
   System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `mouseExit` will occur when the mouse leaves the "context" of the component, including moving from one component to another.  The question is, why would you want this functionality?

Comment: it's just for a homework\